# How to set the text color in an Excel cell via?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl, xlrd

[image]

I knew how to set the color of a cell, but now ，what I need is to set color of the **text**,not the whole cell

Comment: What have you tried? How does your current code look. Please provide some code and try to refrain from using images

Comment: maybe my VPN is unstable， I uploaded the picture yesterday but I can only see it today

Answer (score 1):

```
import xlwt

workbook = xlwt.Workbook()
sheet = workbook.add_sheet('test')

sheet.write(1, 1, (('red ', xlwt.easyfont('color_index red')), \
                   ('blue', xlwt.easyfont('color_index blue'))))

workbook.save('output.xls')
```

[image]